# Triggering Gmail compose UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, next.js, gmail

I have this requirement of opening mail.google.com and opening the compose UI flow with some pre-filled data. This needs to happen via a React application. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const openGmail = () => {

  const subject = encodeURIComponent('Put the subject here');

  const sender = encodeURIComponent('sender@yourdomain.com');
  const body = encodeURIComponent('E-mail body');

  const url = `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&su=${subject}&to=${sender}&body=${body}`;

  window.open(url, '_blank');
};
```

is this enough?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking out for. Is there a way to pre attach files in the gmail as well?